# Hiding a cross tab node in Cognos 11

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-11

I have a cross tab as  in the below picture. I need to hide Col4 in it. When I give box type = none the cross tab node (col5) moves to col4. I tried the below solution but couldn't but still I have this issue.

Steps I followed.

1. Unlock the  button and click on col4 text and removed it.
2. Changed the padding to 0
3. Ran in Excel and got that col4 row as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Col4` is not a column.  It's a value in your data.  What you are asking is the same as hiding a row (or group of rows) from a list.  Add a filter to remove that value from your output.

Using generic object names...

`[Namespace].[Query Subject].[Query Item] <> 'Col4'`

Comment: VAI Jason's answer has been deleted.  I'll make my answer stand alone.